# Create a list of pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, homework

I am trying to take a list of pairs and manipulate the second element. The question is as follows

> Create a list of pairs of numbers and set the resulting list of lists equal to `ans1`. The first number in each pair should be an integer. These integers should range from 0 to 30.  The second number should 2 raised to the power of the first number.
>
> The first five pairs of number are:
>
> ```
> ans1 = {{0,1}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,8}, {4,16}, {5,32}, ...}
> ```
>
> Plot the values stored in `ans1` on a log plot so that the data forms a straight line.

Im just stuck,any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First things first: do you know how to use `Table[]`?

Comment: Yes I tried using Table[] and squaring [[1]] as the second value

Comment: @JoeSimpson Can you show us what you wrote when you tried `Table`?

Comment: 'Table[ans1[[1]], ans1[[1]]^2]'

Comment: @Joe That is syntactically inaccurate. Have you taken a look at the examples in the [documentation of `Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)? Try something like `Table[{i, 2 i}, {i, 0, 10}]` and see if y ou can modify that to your needs.

Comment: Also `ans1 = {#, 2^#} & /@ Range[0, 30]`

Answer (score 2):

```
 ans1 = Table[{n, 2^n}, {n, 0, 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLogPlot[ans1 , Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Perhaps replace `data` with `ans1`?

Comment: @J.M. thanks you for the suggestion. Fixed.